# Selecting a Single Row from Joined Table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables, `Person` and `Address`, as shown below:

**Person**

[image]

**Address**

[image]

Using these tables, I'd like to create a View that has a row for each person in `Person` table but only the most recent address (i.e. max address_id) needs to be picked up as shown below (e.g., Jane's address should be set to '20 Main St' in the View):

[image]

Using below script, it seems like the tables are joining as intended but I don't see any value in the *address* field. I tried several different variations of the same script, but am pretty much spinning my wheels at this point.

Any tips will be much appreciated!

```js
SELECT
  p.person_id AS id,
  p.first_name AS first_name,
  p.last_name AS last_name,
  a.address AS address
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Address a ON
  a.address_id = (
    SELECT MAX(address_id)
    FROM Address
    WHERE p.person_id = a.person_id
  )
```

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. [ask] [Help] Code snippets are for HTML/CSS/Javascript, use a code block, see the edit help.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation.

Comment: When pinned down by a [mre] & clearly described this will be a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. PS LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Comment: @Stu - It's 10.5.10

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tested this query and it meets your need.

```
select p.id, p.name, a.address
from person p
         left join address a 
             on p.id = a.person_id 
             and a.id = (select max(id) from address where person_id = p.id)
;
```